# GraphQl query issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, strapi

I am using [this](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-starter-next-js-blog) starter to build my blog. 
By default you would access an article page at: `http://localhost:3000/article?id=1`, I also would like this: `http://localhost:3000/article?slug=myslug`.

my article controller is as follow:

```
module.exports = {
  async findOne(ctx) {
    //check if the params id is an id or a slug
    const { id } = ctx.params;

    // if you use MongoDB database
    // we are validating that the id match ObjectID format
    if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
      const entity = await strapi.services.article.findOne(ctx.params);
      return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.article });
    }

    // findOne function works only with IDs
    // so we find all and get first entry by using slug
    const [entity] = await strapi.services.article.find({ slug: id });
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.article });
  }
};
```

the article config routes are:

```
...
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/articles/:id",
      "handler": "article.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/articles/:slug",
      "handler": "article.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
...
```

if I do `http://localhost:1337/articles?id=1` or `http://localhost:1337/articles?slug=this-is-my-title` I get the content back as expected.

However, when I hit `http://localhost:3000/article?slug=this-is-my-title`
I get the following:

[image]

inside the pages folder (Front end built with Next.js) I have `pages/article`:

```
const Article = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ARTICLE_QUERY, {
    variables: { slug: router.query.slug }
  });
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>;

  return (
    <Layout>
      {console.log(data)}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

and the `ARTICLE_QUERY` is:

```
const ARTICLE_QUERY = gql`
  query Articles($slug: String!) {
    article(slug: $slug) {
      id
      title
      content
      image {
        url
      }
      category {
        id
        name
      }
      published_at
    }
  }
`;
```

is there any further configuration needed to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

### Error comes from more strict type checking

`article` query needs an `ID!` parameter, providing `slug` (string) doesn't fulfill this requirement.

You need to provide **separate query** (and resolver), like `articleBySlug` for matching url string type parameter.

You also need to check url argument type in some parent component to use proper query (render different subcomponents).

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research I found this solution, which considering that I don't have much experience with GraphQl I am not sure it's the right one:

```
const ARTICLE_QUERY = gql`
  query Articles($slug: String!) {
    articles(where:{slug: $slug}) {
      id
      title
      content
      slug
      image {
        url
      }
      category {
        id
        name
      }
      published_at
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: It's OK **if API supports this type of filtering** ... probably you can define both `id` and `slug` input (not required) parameters (resolver chooses defined one) ... or construct some OR complex filter ... or pass some object as an `filter` input parameter ... you'll find examples on SO